Programmatically Trigger WooCommerce Coupon Form
I am attempting to integrate Yotpo Rewards with our WooCommerce checkout process on WordPress.  So far I have this script that gets the coupon code and inserts it in the coupon input form.  I have been unable to figure out how to submit the form from this script though.
document.body.addEventListener("yotpoLoyaltyDiscountApplied", function(e) {
    var discountCodeInput = document.getElementById('coupon_code');

    // Apply the value from e.detail.discountCode in the discount code's input box
    if (discountCodeInput) {
        discountCodeInput.value = e.detail.discountCode;
    }

    var form = document.querySelector('.checkout_coupon');
    if (form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

Once this script runs the coupon code is successfully applied to the form, I can visibly verify it on the screen, but then the page re-renders.

I found the answer to this.  To trigger the coupon form I could use
form.querySelector('button').click()

So the full script is:
document.body.addEventListener("yotpoLoyaltyDiscountApplied", function(e) {
    var discountCodeInput = document.getElementById('coupon_code');

    // Apply the value from e.detail.discountCode in the discount code's input box
    if (discountCodeInput) {
        discountCodeInput.value = e.detail.discountCode;
    }

    var form = document.querySelector('.checkout_coupon');
    if (form) {
        form.querySelector('button').click()
    }
});

